# How can I change the "Could not reconnect to the server" text in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am using the Blazor server-side.

When the Blazor App disconnect to the remote server, it will shows this:
[image]

I want to change the text ('Could not reconnect to the server...' and so on) of the image above.

I want to change it to the language of our country.

I found the file of the project but found nothing about this.

How can I change it? Thank you.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The Blazor App will check whether there's **a html element with id=`{dialogId}`** in the page:

1. If such an element doesn't exists, it will use the default handler to display message.
2. If this element exists, this element's `class` will be :

   - set as `components-reconnect-show` when attempting to reconnect to the server.
   - set as `components-reconnect-failed` when reconnection failed, probably due to a network failure. To attempt reconnection, call `window.Blazor.reconnect()`.
   - set as `components-reconnect-rejected` when reconnection rejected. The server was reached but refused the connection, and the user's state on the server is lost. To reload the app, call `location.reload()`.

By default, the **`dialogId`** is **`components-reconnect-modal`**. So you can create an element in the page and use CSS to control the content and styles as you like.

Check out the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reflect-the-server-side-connection-state-in-the-ui) for the latest info.

#### Demo:

For example, I create three parts of content to display within the `Pages/_Host.cshtml`:

```html
<div id="components-reconnect-modal" class="my-reconnect-modal components-reconnect-hide">
    <div class="show">
        <p>
            This is the message when attempting to connect to server
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="failed">
        <p>
            This is the custom message when failing 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="rejected">
        <p>
            This is the custom message when refused
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<app>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
</app>

<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

And then let's add some CSS to control the style:

```css
<style>
    .my-reconnect-modal > div{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .components-reconnect-hide > div
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .components-reconnect-show > div
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .components-reconnect-show > .show
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .components-reconnect-failed > div
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .components-reconnect-failed > .failed
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .components-reconnect-rejected >div
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .components-reconnect-rejected > .rejected
    {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Finally, we'll get the following message when attempting to connect or failing to connect:

[image]

Comment: This is good information, but where is *any* of this documented on Microsoft Docs?

Comment: @AaronHudon See [official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reflect-the-connection-state-in-the-ui)

Comment: Thanks.  Strange that they put it under **hosting models**

Comment: @AaronHudon because it only occurs if we use Blazor Server Side model :)

Comment: it seems there is a small error in your style. the class named `components-reconnect-refused` should be correctly named `components-reconnect-rejected`

Comment: It appears this information has moved to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-model-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reflect-the-connection-state-in-the-ui).

Answer (score 18):

For the javascript side of things Blazor exposes a tiny API via the `window.Blazor` object.

One part of this API is the `defaultReconnectionHandler` which allows you to customize the reconnection experience including setting different options for the number of retrys etc.

However, it is also possible to just swap out the logic for displaying the `ReconnectionDisplay`

A simple implemenation looks like this and enables you to to get controll over the process:

```
function createOwnDisplay() {
    return {
        show: () => { alert("put code that shows a toast , ui, or whaterver here"); },
        hide: () => { console.log('foo'); },
        failed: () => { console.log('foo'); },
        rejected: () => { console.log('foo'); }
    };
}

Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectionDisplay = createOwnDisplay();
```

Comment: Well, it is a way to solve it also. But I prefer @itminus 's way more. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Sure, It depends on your use case. If you need more control (e.g. execute custom code when the connection fails) using the API is the way to go. If you just want to swap out UI you can go with @itminus suggestion.

Comment: How can you set the number of retries in the defaultReconnectionHandler?

Answer (score 2):

In your css:

```
#components-reconnect-modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-show{
    display: block;
}
#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-show div.reconnecting {
    display: block;
}
div.reconnecting {
    display: none;
}

#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-failed {
    display: block;
}
#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-failed div.failedToConnect {
    display: block;
}
div.failedToConnect {
    display: none;
}

#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-rejected {
    display: block;
}
#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-rejected div.connectionRejected {
    display: block;
}
div.connectionRejected {
    display: none;
}

#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-hide {
    display: none;
}
```

In _Host body:

```
<div id="components-reconnect-modal">
    <div class="reconnecting">
        Подключение к серверу...
    </div>
    <div class="failedToConnect">
        Не удалось подключиться к серверу <input type="button" value="переподключиться" onclick="ReconnectToServer()" />
        <script>
            function ReconnectToServer() {
                window.Blazor.reconnect();
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="connectionRejected">
        Подключение к серверу прервано <input type="button" value="обновить страницу" onclick="ReloadPage()" />
        <script>
            function ReloadPage() {
                location.reload();
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```