# How to disable "Attempting to reconnect to the server" message on ASP.NET Core producton server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 C# razor pages application that also uses some Blazor-serverside razor components. I have published it to IIS on Windows 2008 R2 Server.
But when browsing the site in Chrome on one andorid mobile phone a message appears periodically:

> Attemting to reconnect to the server

Also when user stays inactive for a while, e.g. turns off the  mobile phone display, a message appears

> Disconnected from server. Reload page ...

The site is not in english and those generic messages are not good for end user exprience. Is there any way how to disable  those messages, or at least translate them to another language?

Comment: You might get some hints from https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10325 For mobile scenarios, Blazor on WebAssembly should be your primary option, not the server side.

Comment: But the problem persists even with no blazor component present on the page,  this message is caused by failed connection to blazor hub, isn't it?

Comment: Found similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404533/how-can-i-change-the-could-not-reconnect-to-the-server-text-in-blazor

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal -- with blazor web assembly there's no need for a connection to the hub.

Comment: @LexLi isn't the Blazor server more suitable for mobile scenarios? because Blazor WebAssembly's initial load time causes first load issues. and pretending support is not very good in Blazor WASM and causes issues in authentication?

Comment: @ZubairKhakwani IMHO Blazor Server relies on good networks (especially corporate networks), so the actual fragile mobile networks can give too many challenges (the app can be out of order during network interrupts). Compared to those, issues like slow hard start and authentication are less significant.

Comment: @LexLi I got your point, as far as I tested Blazor server it works fine even if the internet is slow, It didn't cause an issue until I turn off my data. Blazor Server only requires powerful servers in case of high traffic other than that it works fine. Also if an application is taking 2 mins for the first load, no one is gonna wait that long, with the Blazor server we have more chances of users not leaving our site without seeing what we have to offer.

of course, this is in the case of public sites if someone is building an application for business management WASM is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I have only found a way how to disable Blazor overlays on pages that do not contain any serverside Blazor components. It is quite simple, I have created an empty Interface `IPageWithBlazor` and made all models of razor pages that contain serverside Blazor implement this empty interface. Now I can use the following condition in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@if (this.Model is IPageWithBlazor)
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/blazor.polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
}
```

About translating messages there is [another question that covers the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404533/how-can-i-change-the-could-not-reconnect-to-the-server-text-in-blazor).

Answer (score 32):

There is actually an answer for server-side Blazor as well. According to this: [ASP.NET Core Blazor hosting models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reflect-the-server-side-connection-state-in-the-ui), one can define a div-element with the id `components-reconnect-modal` in the body of `_Host.cshtml` to manipulate the overlay that shows up in case of a connection loss.

That would look something like this:

```
<body>
...
<!-- Blazor overlay -->
<div id="components-reconnect-modal"></div>

<app>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
</app>
...
</body>
```

Blazor applies these custom classes depending on the state of the app. According to the documentation these classes are in effect:

- `components-reconnect-show`: A lost connection. The client is attempting to reconnect. Show the modal.Then you can apply your custom styling to the screen overlay with CSS. If you want to remove them all to you can just choose to not display them at all.
- `components-reconnect-hide`: An active connection is re-established to the server. Hide the modal.
- `components-reconnect-failed`:   Reconnection failed, probably due to a network failure. To attempt reconnection, call `window.Blazor.reconnect()`.
- `components-reconnect-rejected`: Reconnection rejected. The server was reached but refused the connection, and the user's state on the server is lost. To reload the app, call `location.reload()`.

To hide the overlay completely, for instance you can add this CSS:

```
.components-reconnect-show, .components-reconnect-failed, .components-reconnect-rejected {
     display: none;
}
```

If you want a custom look for the overlay, you can just fill the div in `_Host.cshtml` with content to your liking:

```
<div id="components-reconnect-modal" class="my-reconnect-modal components-reconnect-hide">
<div class="show">
    <p>
        // Message when attempting to connect to server
    </p>
</div>
<div class="failed">
    <p>
        // Message when failing to connect
    </p>
</div>
<div class="rejected">
    <p>
        // Message when refused
    </p>
</div>
```

I have no idea if this works client-side  however, as I only work with server-side Blazor.
I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, it is already described in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429936/2224701) that I found later but thanks anyway. I have special situation that I call Blazor components from a normal Razor site with _Layout.cshtml. For me it was weird I was getting the message even without any Blazor component present on the page. It would be very useful to find out, how to set timeouts for javascript components, it behaves strangely on one phone of mine.

Comment: Link is outdated. Maybe update with new one? :) This is fine: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: what are the consequences of hiding these messages?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I found this explanation (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19050) from the Blazor team.

Christiaan Bruin's answer solved my issue, but it changes the reconnect page. I just wanted it not to be fired as the user browses, especially in Firefox. So the way I did is the one suggested on the github issue, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19050#issuecomment-653953887.

```
<script src="_framework\blazor.server.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
    Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectionDisplay = { };
  });
</script>
```

It worked for the Firefox attempts to reconnect and it showed the message correctly when I actually killed the connection.

Comment: `Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler.onConnectionDown = _ => {};` also works for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Hide Blazor Reconnection Messages

Blazer Server uses **SignalR** which is a *mashup* of several client-server connection technologies. It generally tries to connect using WebSocket, EventSource messaging, or long polling Request-Response techniques to keep a connection open with the circuit it creates for each in-memory client connection on the server. So one method may not disable its other *fallback modes* from calling the server and creating more connection errors.

If you dont have access to the code, a *simpler way* is to simply **HIDE THE BLAZOR CONNECTION MESSAGES**. To do that simply create an HTML tag that overrides the default Blazor connection messages that get triggered. This HTML does not have to be compiled into Blazor components but can be part of the HTML page. You can easily override it by simply creating a `<div>` with the right `id` and styled to hide the element, as follows:

```
<div id="components-reconnect-modal" style="display:none;"></div>
```

[Blazor will look for the **first** HTML element with that ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reflect-the-server-side-connection-state-in-the-ui) if there is more than one, so place it at the top of your HTML page.

Blazor will update this HTML element with 3 types of connection error polling states, which show/hide its own HTML messaging using 3 CSS classes it adds to this tag. But you can simply hide all that by hiding the parent div to all its messaging using the HTML above.

Based on the Program.cs services settings the Blazor developer may have customized in `Services.AddServerSideBlazor()` or in the client's JavaScript `_Hosts.cshtml` file (reconnectionOptions: maxRetries), there could be extended time or counts for various connection settings. There are around 8 failed connection attempts on average, I believe. Blazor server retains old in-memory client circuits for a default of 3 minutes, which are then torn down, and a 1 minute timeout for asynchronous JavaScript function invocations.

If these all fail, the app stops in *"rejected"* mode (**components-reconnect-rejected** CSS status) and stops all connection attempts, indicating the server has rejected or discarded the in-memory circuit for the client to connect to. So you just need to hide the messaging until it returns to that rejected state. It should not poll the server again until a refresh/reload of the client browser.

If a developer has modified the JavaScript to reload/refresh the browser URL, then it could continuously call the server. But since you are always hiding the messaging panel, it will appear like nothing is happening to the client. Its not a very intensive call, so this *hiding* technique should work ok.

Ref: [Asp.Net Core SignalR guidance - Reflect the server-side connection state in the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reflect-the-server-side-connection-state-in-the-ui)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my blazor server app, The problem was that I was using .net 7 and had installed SignalR 8.0. I downgrade to 7.0.14 the problem desapear.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to completely delete from _Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

and only put it on pages that use Blazor, like this

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, since even if you have it on a specific page, when your connection to the server fails, then the "Attempting to reconnect to the server" message appears.

Answer (score 0):

for removing "Attempting to reconnect to the server" sentence and that gray overlay when the web socket disconnected or project is stopped in blazor **.net 8** add this line css style to the **app.css** file that is in wwwroot folder :

```
#components-reconnect-modal {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: @M Komaei: do you know what caused it to show all the time? I'm having the same issue and I'm trying to find the root cause?

Comment: When the web socket disconnect between browser and server