# Blazor Server - simple hyperlink to external site causes "attempting to reconnect.."

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Any simple link to an external site from my Blazor Server site works....but while the site loads the user sees the Blazor "Attempting to reconnect to the server: 1 of 8" message first.

How do I get rid of that and provide a more seamless experience?

I have tried coding my own javascript exit routine by listening to the click event and manually doing window.location.href = url; with the same results.

I have also tried calling Blazor.disconnect() before jumping to the external site, but again no luck.

I tried embedding calls to a NavigationManager in my code, but that's really ugly, and I didn't have much luck with that either.

...surely a very simple scenario! - my code is simply:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">Go</a>
```

Comment: This is because the default behavior of a Blazor Server application is to maintain a persistent connection with the server, and when the user navigates to an external site, the connection is lost, so I guess using NavigationManager is a best option there

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the opportunity to test this myself, but the answer on this post here might be useful in setting the CSS to "display: none" when the link is clicked.

[How to disable "Attempting to reconnect to the server" message on ASP.NET Core producton server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236834/how-to-disable-attempting-to-reconnect-to-the-server-message-on-asp-net-core-p)

Answer (score 0):

with thanks to @Silky, and @Begging - based on those answers I came up with the following which worked for me.

approach: on click of any link - see if it looks like an external link, and if so add a body class that causes the built-in "reconnect" overlay to be hidden, and change the cursor. Note that adding a class to the body was the way to go for me as trying to affect the overlay (#components-reconnect-modal) has issues as it gets generated/inserted in an unknown (to me) way.

Javascript (JQuery):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', handleExternalLink);
handleExternalLink: function (e) {
    var ref = $(this).attr('href');
     if (ref.indexOf('http') != -1) {
        $('body').removeClass('hide-reconnect').addClass('hide-reconnect');
        window.location.href = ref;
    }
}
```

Css:

```css
html body.hide-reconnect #components-reconnect-modal {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

html body.hide-reconnect, html body.hide-reconnect a:hover {
    cursor: wait;
}
```