# How or should I remove "Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm just wondering if I can remove the overlay "Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality"?

I found an answer on how to do it here:
[How to disable "Attempting to reconnect to the server" message on ASP.NET Core producton server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236834/how-to-disable-attempting-to-reconnect-to-the-server-message-on-asp-net-core-p)

I'm new to Blazor, first time using it.

1. Is there something I'm doing wrong, Is this the reason it shows in production?
2. If I decide to just hide the messages, what are the consequences?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you remove this message, then how will people know that they've been disconnected?  I cannot conceive of a case where you'd want to do this.

Comment: I'm just wondering because in say MVC, it never says a message like this,  if I build a site for a customer, and they see that, they may think something is wrong?

Comment: Yeah, the message is nothing unusual. It happens when SignalR connection is severed and circuit in the server is disposed. So the message is necessary to indicate that the connection has been lost. It's just a "charming" side of Blazor Server Side and technology it is based on, that is SignalR. So far there is no fix.