# Blazor Server issue with application refresh after long periods of inactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have such a problem. Using this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0 I wanted to set up a custom procedure for reconnecting to the Blazor Server. I'm using .Net version 6.0. While in version 7.0 I see that there is an official script for modification "boot.js", in version 6.0 there are fewer options (I think?). What I mean is that I notice a problem with disconnecting the application if the Chrome tab is not used for at least 3 minutes. Ok, this can be bypassed by turning off "energy saving", but I haven't found this option on mobile devices.

I found a solution on stack, but it only hides the window with information about retrying the connection and you have to click on a control 2 or 3 times to refresh the connection. Link to solution: [How to disable "Attempting to reconnect to the server" message on ASP.NET Core producton server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236834/how-to-disable-attempting-to-reconnect-to-the-server-message-on-asp-net-core-p)

I'm afraid that trying to migrate to version 7.0 will cause the application to crash. I don't know if it's even possible to migrate?

Comment: In the docs (Signal R) it suggestsed to use the Web Lock mechanism to prevent a tab going to sleep. The recommendation is also mentioned in .NET 6 web docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#bsleep. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638451/reconnecting-issue-in-blazor-server/74642664#74642664

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate to a newer version of .NET, visual studio now comes with an upgrade assistant which might work for you. right click on solution -> upgrade.

However, this should work:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{
    options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
}
```

Change the timespan to what you want, basically this will cache the connection on the server and if a client is back within the given timespan connection will still be active.

Also havent tried this but ive seen it used before

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
});
```

which sends a ping from server every 15 seconds to keep connection alive, not sure how effective it is, might need more research.