# Blazor custom reload / connection lost text

Tags: blazor

I write application in Blazor dotnet core 3.1 and want to customize the default texts when reloading / lost connection to server to localized text with animated svg to let User know that it is reconnecting.

Problem is that my current verison don't hide the text, don't know how or where to let it be visible / invisible.

Used this links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="components-reconnect-modal" class="my-reconnect-modal components-reconnect-hide">
    <div class="show">
        <p>
            This is the message when attempting to connect to server
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="failed">
        <p>
            This is the custom message when failing 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="refused">
        <p>
            This is the custom message when refused
        </p>
    </div>
</div>       
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>    
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Style:

```
.components-reconnect-hide > div
{
    display: none;
}

.components-reconnect-show > div
{
    display: none;
}
.components-reconnect-show > .show
{
    display: block;
}

.components-reconnect-failed > div
{
    display: none;
}
.components-reconnect-failed > .failed
{
    display: block;
}

.components-reconnect-refused >div
{
    display: none;
}
.components-reconnect-refused > .refused
{
    display: block;
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish correct?

Thx!

Comment: Post your css classes definition for `my-reconnect-modal` and `components-reconnect-hide` the issue is probably somewhere here

Comment: .components-reconnect-hide > div
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .components-reconnect-show > div
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .components-reconnect-show > .show
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .components-reconnect-failed > div
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .components-reconnect-failed > .failed
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .components-reconnect-refused >div
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .components-reconnect-refused > .refused
    {
        display: block;
    }

Comment: In your question not in comment, this is unreadable

Comment: Hi agua, yes sure!
Also used this link for it, but the CSS tags won't disappear: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404533/how-can-i-change-the-could-not-reconnect-to-the-server-text-in-blazor

Comment: you can see in image: https://ibb.co/Yh2cTDY

Comment: You didn't post `my-reconnect-modal` class def. Is it a miss up or you don't have one ?

Comment: I used this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404533/how-can-i-change-the-could-not-reconnect-to-the-server-text-in-blazor

Comment: but the css isn't changed correct after reload automatically by             document.location.reload();