# Blazor Server Custom Reconnect Page Not showing up

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a custom Reconnect page in blazor server app.I have followed the following link to achieve this
[How can I change the "Could not reconnect to the server" text in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404533/how-can-i-change-the-could-not-reconnect-to-the-server-text-in-blazor)
Here is my code sample for blazor reconnect page

```
<div class="modal modal-full modal-hotel-details troubleshoot-error show my-reconnect-modal components-reconnect-hide" id="components-reconnect-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @*my-reconnect-modal components-reconnect-hide*@
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-between py-2">
                        <div class="col-8 m-auto text-center">
                            <div>Connection lost -- please wait, attempting to reconnect</div>
                            <div>(Current reconnect attempt : <span>1/8</span>)</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 m-auto text-center py-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2">Check internet connectivity</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Reconnect</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-between pt-5">
                        <div class="col-8 m-auto mt-5">
                            <div class="form-row  sticky" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                                <div class="col-6 py-4 m-auto">
                                    <div class="card card-hotel-block-top with-shade card-booking-details">
                                        <div class="card-body view-list">
                                            <div class="form-row view-blocks">
                                                <div class="col-12 ">
                                                    <div class="form-row">
                                                        <div class="col-12 m-auto text-center py-1">
                                                            <h4 class="m-auto">Error troubleshooting</h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-12 py-3">
                                                            <span><img class="trouble-success" src="images/icons/complete-check.svg"></span>
                                                            <span class="loading-text">Internet connectivity check successful</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-12 pb-3">
                                                            <span class="text-danger"><i class="icon-invalid-alert failure-icon"></i></span>
                                                            <span class="loading-text">Unable to establish communication with the web server</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-12 pt-1">
                                                            <p class="small-theme-font">Establishing web server communication failed. Please contact IT administrator.</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.my-reconnect-modal > div {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #fff;
opacity: 0.8;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

.components-reconnect-hide > div {
display: none;
}

.components-reconnect-show > div {
display: none;
}

.components-reconnect-show > .show {
display: block;
}

.components-reconnect-failed > div {
display: none;
}

.components-reconnect-failed > .failed {
display: block;
}

.components-reconnect-rejected > div {
display: none;
}

.components-reconnect-rejected > .rejected {
display: block;
}

#blazor-error-ui {
background: lightyellow;
bottom: 0;
box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
display: none;
left: 0;
padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}

```
#blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75rem;
    top: 0.5rem;
}
```

.loader-check.spinner-border {
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
vertical-align: top;
border: 0.15em solid currentColor;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
}

.loading-text {
margin-left: 15px;
font-size: 12px;
}

.trouble-success {
height: 20px;
}

.failure-icon {
position: relative;
font-size: 20px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: Can you show your CSS? You have to define the styles in CSS to show and hide the modal and then Blazor dynamically applies the classes to the main `div` such as `components-reconnect-show`, `components-reconnect-failed`, and `components-reconnect-rejected`.